# Create a separate download link in Github

Tags: windows, hyperlink, download, github, repository

My Github repository has the source code and a .exe file to be downloaded and installed on Windows.
Some of my clients are getting problems because they can't identify the installer on the zip file they download.
Is there a way to create an easy download link with only some specific files of the repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm sorry. I just find it now.
So I'll post how I did it so other may find the answer too:
You just have to click on the .exe file and on the right side (a pretty small thing for me) you'll se the option "Raw" which if you click will download the file.
I guess I was a little precipitate.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the API from github
You could also create a website for your clients to mainly download your files.

http://develop.github.com/p/repo.html